# PHP how to create JSON with localization arguments for APNS

Tags: php, json, apple-push-notifications

I want to send JSON in an APNS with the following:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
            "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "Frank"]
        },
        "sound" : "default"
    },
}
```

Can anyone explaine how I can create this in PHP?

I have the following for JSON without the key/args:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
       'alert ' => 'This is my messsage',
       'sound' => 'default'
);

$payload = json_encode($body);
```

I have tried to replace the 'This is my message' with an array for loc-key and loc-args but that does not work. Also jus putting in the data as string does not work..
Hope someone can help me. I have tried multiple options and variations but nothing works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$body = array(
    "aps" => array(
        "alert" => array(
            "loc-key" => "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
            "loc-args" => array( "Jenna", "Frank" )
        ),
        "sound" => "default",
    ),
);
echo json_encode($body);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$body['aps']['alert'] = array(
     "loc-key" => "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
     "loc-args" => array("Jenna", "Frank")
);
```

just replace the content